# Why YouTube-dl download only link come from YouTube in meteorjs app?

Tags: javascript, video, meteor, youtube

I checked  all questions that treats the YouTube-dl problem but did not find the same problem of my question;

When I download a YouTube video with node YouTube-dl in my meteorjs app, all it's OK (in chrome), except that in Firefox open video in new tab instead downloading it; but when I try to download video (in chrome) from another site like Facebook, twitter or whatever else, it throw this error in console

```
Error: Internal server error [500]
```

And this one on the terminal

```
Exception while invoking method 'commandliiiine'Error: No video id found: https://www.facebook.com/sawtelghad/videos/1070722126318944/
```

And this my code in the server

```
 var ytdl = Meteor.npmRequire('ytdl-core');
  var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");

Meteor.methods({
    'commandliiiine': function(url){

      this.unblock();
      var future = new Future();

      ytdl.getInfo(url, function(err, result) {

        future.return(result);
      }); 

      return future.wait();
    }
});
```

And this is the code in the client

```
 Meteor.call('commandliiiine', url, function(error, result){
        if (result) {
          Session.set('videoTitle', result.title);
          Session.set('videoImage', result.thumbnail_url);




       } else {
          console.log('error:'+ error);
       }
      });
```

This the version of youtube-dl I use:"ytdl-core":"0.7.9"

Could anyone help me with this issue !! please

Thank's a lot

Comment: @Roemer,  please can you tell me what and why you edit my question !!

Comment: I removed the 'Facebook' tag, since your question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Roemer so, there is no video on facebook to download??

Answer (score 0):

What is your submit URL function?

Also I've checked for Facebook and in the result object you're returning to the client, there isn't any thumbnail_url for example.

Change your code to:

```
Meteor.call('commandliiiine', url, function(error, result){
    if (result) {
      console.log(result);
   } else {
      console.log('error:'+ error);
   }
  });
```

and open developer console on Chrome and look at your returned object. You can only access object keys that are printed there for each video sharing site.

Comment: There is no result in the console, it throw an error as I explain before